# Error crs when reading a shapefile with geopandas in jupyter

Tags: pandas, geopandas

I´m trying to read a shapefile with geopandas

```
Quito_full =gpd.read_file('./shapefiles/administraciones_zonales.shp')
```

Simple as that but I keep getting the following error

```
CRSError: Invalid projection: epsg:32717: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, geodetic_crs_auth_name, geodetic_crs_code, conversion_auth_name, conversion_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition, deprecated FROM projected_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such column: area_of_use_auth_name)
```

This are my versions

```
print(sys.version)
3.8.12 (default, Oct 12 2021, 03:01:40) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
import pyproj
print(pyproj.__version__)
2.6.1.post1
import geopandas
print(geopandas.__version__)
0.9.0
```

Is there anyway to fix this error, I have been trying everything!.

Comment: where have you got this shape file from?  web link would be helpful

Comment: Definitely try updating pyproj as [RobRaymond suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71039341/3888719). This can also occur with conflicting versions of pyproj or incomplete installations (usually with pip). If you're using a combination of pip and conda, I'd try deleting your environment and installing it fresh, making sure to install geopandas and pyproj from the same channels (I'd use `conda-forge`), e.g. `conda create -n myenv -c conda-forge python pyproj geopandas [others...]`

Answer (score 2):

- have downloaded shape file from here https://hub.arcgis.com/datasets/esrimarketing::administraciones-zonales/explore?location=-0.167571%2C-78.559309%2C10.38
- it is epsg:4326,  but then projected to epsg:32717.  No issues
- your **pyproj** and **geopandas** versions are a bit outdated.  Your error primarily points to an issue with **pyproj**

```
from pathlib import Path
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file(list(Path.home().joinpath("Downloads").glob("**/Administraciones_Zonales.shp"))[0])
gdf.to_crs("epsg:32717").explore()
```

#### versions

```
import pyproj, sys
print(gpd.__version__, pyproj.__version__, sys.version)
```

```
0.10.2 3.3.0 3.9.10 (main, Jan 15 2022, 11:48:00) 
[Clang 13.0.0 (clang-1300.0.29.3)]
```